# Power setting shows 194 hours and 37 minutes remaining, how?

Tags: 16.04, battery

The image shows my laptop battery charged to 99% but the power setting shows 194 hours and 37 minutes remaining - is it possible using Ubuntu? If yes then how?

[image]

Comment: 194 hours and 37 min = 8 days, 2 hours and 37 min, not sure a battery on a computer can do that, how many power life time do you see on other OS (if you have another one in this computer)?

Comment: something is wrong - in my laptop or OS ,please any help will be appreciated .

Comment: 1. Why is there no setting after "When power is critically low"? 2. On my laptop I don't see the remaining time text, so possibly it is laptop dependent. You should add the laptop model and any other relevant hardware info. to your question. 3. You could run on battery power, and track remaining % vs. time remaining to see if there is a tracking issue.

Comment: Did you ever let the battery discharge to something like 10 or 20%? You should do that so that the system can adjust its estimates to the real data. The figures should become more accurate over time. Also, can you [edit] your question and add the output of the terminal command `upower --dump` (as plain, code formatted text please)?